# Why is there http.get but no http.post in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, post

I know `http` exposes `get` since it's such a frequently used method, in the words of the authors of *Node: Up and Running*, but I do not know why there is not a similar `post` method.  I know `post` also must take a body but that seems trivial. So - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isaacs doesn't even want the `http` module in Node's core, likely it was put there since it is so often used; but they figured you could do your own for anything else with [`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

Also if they do `POST` then why not `PUT` and `DELETE` and etc. Likely they put in the `get` wrapper, and then thought there was no reason to keep doing that in the core. It is just there as a quick helper for the common `GET` request.

Node has the philosophy of "If it doesn't *have* to be in core, then it shouldn't" so, take that as you will.

Comment: Who is Isaac?  And this begs the question; why figure I can do what I want for post but not get?

Comment: @djechlin Isaacs is the lead maintainer of node, and you can do `GET` in `http.request`. The `.get()` helper is just that, a small helper since it is by far the most common request type. It just wraps `http.request` for you, for a simple call for the most common requests.